# How do I add an escape key sequence to SpaceVim.d/init.toml

Tags: spacevim

I'm a Spacemacs user and I am trying SpaceVim for the first time.

There are a couple of settings I would like to port over.
I use ",." to escape, with a delay of half a second, as shown in my Spacemacs config:

```
  (setq-default evil-escape-key-sequence ",."
                evil-escape-unordered-key-sequence "true"
                evil-escape-delay 0.5)
```

I also switch to normal state after 15 seconds of idle time.

```
  ;; When in insert mode and idle, return to evil-normal-state
  (run-with-idle-timer 15 t 'evil-normal-state)
```

How do I set the same settings in the SpaceVim.d/init.toml file?

Answer (score 0):

currently no, but I think you can use bootstrap function. in the function you can use vim script to create this key binding

`inoremap ,. <esc>`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm very new to vim. Where would I save this and how would SpaceVim load it?  Would this be inside the SpaceVim.d folder and would I need to add something to my init.toml to instruct it to load the file.

Comment: where do you mean by "in the function" ? It's really not clear where one should add a custom esc sequence for Spacevim, which is a pretty core part of using Vim for a lot of people.

Comment: In bootstrap function, you can use vim script.